# how to set a radio button state to checked with css?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

i have a group of radio buttons with a default checked one. like this:

```
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="rd1" checked="">
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="rd2">
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="rd3">
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="rd4">
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="rd5">
```

i know there is ways to add checked attribute with javascript. my question is how to add checked attr to selected radio button with css?

Comment: CSS as its name suggests is meant for styling. DOM manipulation should be done with Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the **initially checked box**, you should simply move the "checked" attribute to the desired element in your **HTML**, if you want to **style the currently checked box** you can use the following **CSS** selector: `input[type=checkbox]:checked`and if you want to **change the checked state** by any other action than clicking a checkbox you must use **JS**.

The attribute "checked" differs from the actual `.checked` property in JS: while `elem.getAttribute('checked')` will only return other than `null` if the attribute is already set in your HTML (could also been changed via JS), `elem.checked` will always return a boolean (true/false) indicating if this box is currently checked.