# input in label for radio button

Tags: html, forms, radio-button, label

I am trying to put a text input into a label. The label is referenced to a radio button. But when I click the text input field, the radio button is not checked.

It is for emails so no JavaScript is allowed.

Why won't this work?

```html
<label id="id1" for="label1">
        <input type="text" name="label">
        hello
    </label>
<input type=radio id="label1" name="group">
```

Comment: It does not work because the input field does not bubble the click event

Comment: So there is no possibility to do it?

Comment: Not really. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328454/how-to-set-a-radio-button-state-to-checked-with-css